# Can't launch tests with XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Everything worked fine, but on some build I've got this (when trying to launch tests):

> The test bundle at "path to xctest" could not be loaded because it is
>   built for a different architecture than the currently-running test rig
>   (which is running as x86_64)

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to rebuild, clean, relaunch Xcode, reboot OS X...

Comment: I have the same problem on iOS (using cocoa pods) but no luck so far. My project was created before XCode 5 was released.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the solution! You can't currently build for iOS 6 and iOS7 x64. So if you want iOS7 x64, you have to change the build variable (click on the project and then on the target) Architectures to the value "...including 64-bit". Unfortunately any iOS prior to 7 isn't supported.

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Solved it myself, but final answer is same as yours! Anyhow, thanks a lot!

Comment: On SO you can answer your question yourself and get points, too :). But thanks for the checkmark! :)

Comment: One more thing here. You can still test without iOS7 x64. Leave target as is (without x64 architecture added) and test, using iOS7 simulator (any, but iOS not earlier than 7) - this worked for me.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this: To make the iOS 6 test target run, arm64 must be removed from valid architectures of the test target.

Comment: Great tip, saved my day! Note that I was able to get the iOS 6 tests to run even with arm64 enabled, but I was testing a static library so it might be a different situation.